# Document print without using print preview in universal windows application

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

How to slient print perform in UWP application.
Is there any solution to print documents without using print preview in UWP.
How to configure printer drivers in UWP so that print direct in printer.

Please send a suggestion to me for above query.

Comment: Any attempts already?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution to print documents without using print preview in UWP

Do you just want to disable preview? If so, you can refer to the UWP Official [Printing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) Sample and see the scenario `Scenario6DisablePreview` page.

If you want to hide the Print Popup dialog, you can see the answer in this similar thread: [UWP : Print with out Printer Popup Dialoag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644492/uwp-print-with-out-printer-popup-dialoag)

Please also pay attention to @ Stefan Wick MSFT's comment in that thread.